# How to consume restful services from another restful service in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, rest, wcf, service

I have an URL of one restful service, I want to consume this restful service from another restful service.

Suppose URL is first rest service is `"http://testapi.com/services/rest/?method=getList&key=123”`

```
Restful service 1  - > Restful service 2  -> asp.net client application
```

Could you provide any example with code and configuration settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HttpClient](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client). The example in the post is using a console application, but you can still use it from a Web Api project (which I have on some of my projects).

Example get async:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("YOURURIHERE");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // New code:
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync>Product>();
    }
}
```